# Getting a GPS module to give out the right values(most likely a buffer issue)

Tags: gps

I'm currently having an issue where my GPS values come out mostly scrambled besides the $GPGGA and a little bit of the other information. I believe it is a buffer issue and I was wondering what buffer and other settings you guys have successfully used. I'm coding on Altair Embed, Formerly VisSim. I commented a picture of my serial settings as well as the messages I am getting right now. The GPS module is the
EM-506(https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/EM506_um.pdf). I would appreciate any help or ideas you guys have. Thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apilp.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Gjs4EJB